# How to validate saved record without changes in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

My Rails5.1.4 project ha had Station model and there are some saved records.

```
class Station < ApplicationRecord
end

> Station.first
# => #<Station:0x0055f5ca447d78 id: 1, name: nil>
```

Then I added new validation(presence checking for name).

```
class Station < ApplicationRecord
  with_options on: [:publishing] do
    # added new validation
    validates :name, presence: true
  end
end
```

Here, if validate! method called without attributes changing. validate! method returned true.

```
> reload!
> station = Station.first
# => #<Station:0x0055f5cf4b6228 id: 1, name: nil>
> station.validate!(context: :publishing) # without attributes changing
# => true
# expected ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid raising.
```

Here is an one problem for me.

I expected ActiveRecord raised `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` because I added presence validation for name.

can I do like this?

Regards

Comment: are you handling situation for existing records?

Comment: thanks for your comment! no i'm not. just take a record and call validate! method

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Rails 5.1.4, working like expected

Comment: oh, I am sorry validates method is in with_options block with on option and I call validate! method with context key. I updated my question.

Comment: @kolas I'm working too without with_options. sorry. I wanna validate with with_options block

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrong argument. Try to call it like this:

```
station.validate!(:publishing)
```

Docs: https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Validations/validate%21

Comment: yeah! Thanks! I had thought I can use `validate!` method like `save!`. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Try using **valid?**

```
station = Station.first
station.valid?
```

It should work fine :)

**Note:** 
other answers recommend using **validate** both should work fine as **validate** is an alias for **valid?**. Check [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-validate)

Comment: more info here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F

Comment: `valid?(:publishing)` shows me validation result! that's nice! thanks!